# Python : Transforming a complex array to polar form

Tags: python, arrays, implementation, complex-numbers

I have a np.array with shape (300,300) with complex values a+bj.
I would like to transform each element to the polar form R*exp{j*O}

I've tryied

```
cmath.polar(data)
```

But doesn't work for array, so I try something like that

```
complexe = np.zeros((len(data),len(data[0])))
count_arr = 0
for arr in data:
    count_item = 0
    for itm in arr:
        complexe[count_arr][count_item] = cmath.polar(itm)
        count_item = count_item +1
    count_arr = count_arr +1
```

It doesn't work because the output of cmath.polar is a tuple (I think).

I am a beginner in python so any help will be welcome!

Comment: First, know that you can make the counters work automatically by using `for count_arr, arr in enumerate(data)` and `for count_item, itm in enumerate(arr)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get your R and O directly in numpy:

```
R = np.abs(z), O = np.angle(z)
```